# EF6 Many to many cascade delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

We have a EF project that initially was Database first. We have later on migrated to Code first, which means there are tons of migrations that does not exist in the code.

Now we need to create a fresh database for this project. So, erased all migrations and did a new inital migration. When we the try to update/create the database, we encounter a problem with cascade delete and many to many-relationship. The relationsship is defined with fluent mapping as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Assistant>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Clients)
            .WithMany(e => e.Assistants)
            .Map(m => 
                m.ToTable("Clients_Bind_Assistants")
                .MapLeftKey("AssistantID")
                .MapRightKey("ClientID")
            );
```

When running update-database we receive the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Clients_Bind_Assistants_dbo.Clients_ClientID' on table 'Clients_Bind_Assistants' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Can we somehow with Fluent mapping define cascade delete to false?

**Edit:**

```
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

solves this current problem, but we have a few many-to-many relationships in the project, which makes this a scary solution.

Comment: Not an expert myself, but can you try adding `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`? For more on that, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships

Comment: @PeterB It's not possible to use that with many-to-many. :/